# Algorithm to find the angle of a direction

Tags: geometry, vectors, algorithms

I need to translate the distance between two points into an angle from 0 to 359. To do this I use the new position coordinates which is defined by a vector and subtract the original position. This generates a difference which I can then use to define the slopes absolute value (I know it can be done with out the absolute value if I change my code up).
[image]
When the movement is within the NW_North section the angle will be 135 when the absolute value of the slope is 1 and as the slope converges on infinity the angle will be 180. The challenging thing is I need to break up all possible values into 45 separate angles but I have no idea what the correct algorithm is since it will need to be rounded to the nearest integer. Also I dont think the center is actually 2 but its close to it and it appears that as the distance between each red line doubles the slope gets squared but I could be wrong.

```
 public static int getNormalizedMovementAngle(Vector3d vector, double x, double z) {
    final double zDifference = vector.getZ() - z;
    final double xDifference = vector.getX() - x;
    final double slope = Math.abs(zDifference / xDifference);

    if(vector.getX() < x) {
        if(vector.getZ() == z) return 90;
        else if(vector.getZ() < z) {
            if(slope == 1) return 135;
            else if(slope > 1) {
                //Formula needs to go here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyways if anyone knows how I can use the slope to generate 45 different angles between NW and North please let met know thank you!!

Edit: I can use the following to get the angle for NW_North however I noticed that its a bit off for West_NW why is that exactly? I divided the side up into 45 sections which then allowed me to decrement the slope by 0.02222 and it appears that my equation does not assign each angle an equal width section. This means multiple sections get assigned the same angle (max of 2) for the first half and then it starts skipping an angle till it finally converges on 90 degrees.

```
 return Math.toIntExact(Math.round(90 * (2 - Math.pow(2, -slope))));
```

Does anyone know how to get atan2 to use the domain of 0 to 360 degrees? I can also swap the x and z difference values for my atan2 equation depending on which quadrant we are in if that makes the calculations easier (for example SW_West could go from 1 to infinity while South_SW can go from 1 to 0).

```
final int angle = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(Math.atan2(zDifference, xDifference) * (180.0 / Math.PI)));
```

Comment: You cannot translate a "distance... into an angle."

Comment: A line with slope $2$ has an angle approximately $63.4$ degrees from horizontal. Halfway between $45$ and $90$ would be $67.5$ degrees, and  $63.4$ is kinda sorta close to that, but if you really want halfway between $45$ and $90$ why not use $67.5$? There is a function called atan2 that will convert your vector to a compass direction almost directly (you just have to convert the result from radians to degrees). You could do the entire calculation in one line of code.

Comment: Yes I know about that and tried it but I cant get it to work for all quadrants

Comment: The coordinate system I have to use is different from what you would normally see so I dont know how to use that method.

Comment: If you want to respond to someone in comments use @<username> to tag them. Then they'll be notified immediately that there's a message for them.

Comment: One good thing about $\operatorname{atan2}$ is that it understands four quadrants. It outputs radians rather than degrees so you have to multiply by $180/\pi$ to get the angle in degrees; also, after converting to degrees its output goes from $-180$ to $180$ instead of $0$ to $360$, so either you add $360$ to all negative results or you make $\operatorname{atan2}$ give you an angle relative to the north direction and add $180$ to it to get the angle you want. If you tried $\operatorname{atan2}$ and it didn't work, show what you did and what results you got. It's probably easily fixed.

Comment: Well I need it to go from 0 to 360 but I dont see how adding 360 to negative results will help since that wont make atan2 give a result within the domain of 0 to 360. I will happily use the atan2 method if I can figure out how to get it to use the correct domain since my current approach has a small margin of error when the slope is less than 1 which is an issue (I need it to be exact).

Comment: @DavidK alright I edited my original post to show you what I have tried so far when it comes to using atan2 but I am still stuck on getting atan2 to use the domain of 0 to 360.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading of your diagram and code, you want the following angles (measured in degrees) as results from various input values of xDifference and zDifference:

\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{xDifference} & \text{zDifference} & \text{angle} \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 45 \\
-1 & 0 & 90 \\
-1 & -1 & 135 \\
0 & -1 & 180 \\
1 & -1 & 225 \\
1 & 0 & 270 \\
1 & 1 & 315
\end{array}

Obviously you also want to accept values other than $0$ and $\pm1,$ but the cases above are more than enough test cases to figure out the correct use of $\operatorname{atan2}$ in your program.

Now here are some results you could get using the `Math.atan2` function
on two variables $v_1$ and $v_2$:

\begin{array}{cccc}
v_1 & v_2 & \operatorname{atan2}(v_1,v_2) \times \dfrac{180}{\pi} & \operatorname{atan2}(v_1,v_2) \times \dfrac{180}{\pi} + 360 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 45 \\
1 & 0 & 90 \\
1 & -1 & 135 \\
0 & -1 & 180 \\
-1 & -1 & -135 & 225 \\
-1 & 0 & -90 & 270 \\
-1 & 1 & -45 & 315
\end{array}

Compare this table with the first one.
Notice that the first five lines of the third column are identical in the two tables. The last three lines of that column are different, but if you add $360$ in those cases -- as shown in the fourth column -- you get the numbers you wanted.
This works because of the principle that if you turn in a certain direction (clockwise, in your case) either by the angle $\theta$ or by the angle $\theta + 360^\circ$, in both cases you end up facing in the same direction.

The other difference between the two tables is that the signs in the first column of the second table are opposite the signs in the first table.
The second columns, on the other hand, are the same.
These facts tell you that zDifference is the correct variable to pass as the **second** argument of $\operatorname{atan2}$ (not the first)
and that you can get the correct first argument by reversing the sign of xDifference.

So that gives us something like this:

```
angle = Math.atan2(-xDifference, zDifference) * 180.0 / Math.PI);
if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
```

You can round the result to an integer either before or after the statement `if (angle < 0) angle += 360;`.
The difference is that if you round after adding, you will sometimes round up to $360,$ whereas if you round before adding you will always get an integer in the range from $0$ to $359$ inclusive.

---

More generally, in case you want to use these ideas in other situations where the axes may be named differently and the angle may be measured differently,
whichever axis points in the "angle $0$" direction is the one you want to use for the **second** argument of `Math.atan2`, because that's where you would use the $x$ coordinate if you wanted the $x$ axis to point in the direction at "angle $0$".
The axis that points in the "angle $90$" direction should be the **first** argument.

You also need to get the signs of the arguments correct for the kind of output you want.
If one of your coordinate axes points in exactly the opposite direction from the  "angle $0$" direction or the  "angle $90$" direction, you change sign on that coordinate before passing it to $\operatorname{atan2}$.

In any case, when in doubt, map out the results you want and the results $\operatorname{atan2}$ gives you in a two tables as shown above, and match up the columns to figure out which variables get passed to $\operatorname{atan2}$ in what ways.

Comment: Yes but this method still has the same issue as the method I used before. For example if my zDifference is 1 and my xDifference is 2 I get an angle of 297 however I know the center should be 293 because there is 45 degrees between 270 and 315 and half of 45 is 22.5 and since xDif is twice as big it should land in the center which rounds up to be 293 which means your method is 4 degrees off while the other one I tried was 3 degrees off.

Comment: "since xDif is twice as big it should land in the center"? I thought you wanted to measure angles in degrees. If you have a triangle with sides $1,1,\sqrt2$ the angles are $90,45,45$ (in degrees). For a triangle with sides $1,2,\sqrt3$ the angles are $90,26.565,63.435$, approximately.

Comment: I do want to measure it in degrees but I need it to work correctly with my system. For example by moving twice as much in the positive x direction compared to the positive z direction (aka xDif = 2 and zDif = 1) you would expect the motion to be coming from the origin and pointing East_SE (more specifically exactly half way between Se and East. This is because when xDif and zDif are equal we will have a slope of 1 which means we will be moving SE since it is 45 degrees away from both East and South. However in my above example since xDif  is 2x larger the vector would be half way between both.

Comment: If your system says that the angle of a $1,2,\sqrt3$ triangle is $22.5$ then you are not measuring angles in degrees. If you want a direction that goes exactly halfway between SE and east, you can go $2$ units east and $0.828427$ unit south. If you go $2$ units east and $1$ unit south you will wind up at a point that is closer to the SE line than to the E line. If you're closer to one side of an angle than the other I don't see how that can possibly be viewed as "exactly half way between Se and East".

Comment: Maybe there is some other motivation for not using the actual angles that your lines make, but if so, it would be useful to know what it is. For example if this is for some kind of game where the only vectors you are interested in have relatively small integer coordinates. (But that doesn't seem to be the case since you are contemplating a line with slope $\sqrt2$.)

Comment: Yes I understand and I think your atan2 method is correct. The reason this problem was set up so unconventionally is because I am adding something to an already made game so I have to use their screwy system. But anyways thank you for the help!

Comment: "... adding something to an already made game so I have to use their screwy system." Oh! That explains a lot. I think anyone who has worked with software long enough has been in a situation like this. I don't know if I was any help dealing with the game, but maybe the answer will be useful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Last edit:

If you were using the ordinary convention for angles, reading from $0$ at East counterclockwise then the ordinary $\arctan$ function will convert slopes to angles. in the upper half plane. You should be able to massage it to work in your coordinate system for the whole circle.

That sais, here are the answers for the hack I first thought of:

Let $x$ be the absolute value of the slope in the quadrant you care about.

Then in the NW quadrant
$$
\theta = 90\left( 2 - 2^{ -x}\right) .
$$
When $x$ is near $0$ that is near $90$. When $x=1$ it's $135$. When $x$ is near $\infty$ it's near $180$.

(Your choice of angles is a little weird from a mathematical perspective. I'd expect North to be 90 and West to be 180.)

In the NE quadrant
$$
\theta = 180 + 90\times 2^{ -x}.
$$
When $x$ is near $0$ that is near $270$. When $x=1$ it's $225$. When $x$ is near $\infty$ it's near $180$.

In the SE quadrant
$$
\theta = 360 - 90\times 2^{ -x}.
$$
When $x$ is near $0$ that is near $270$. When $x=1$ it's $315$. When $x$ is near $\infty$ it's near $360$.

In the Sw quadrant
$$
\theta =  90\times 2^{ -x}.
$$
When $x$ is near $0$ that is near $90$. When $x=1$ it's $45$. When $x$ is near $\infty$ it's near $0$.
Edit in response to comment.

Comment: Oh how did you know that yea that does work. What would the solution for the one that goes from 1 to negative infinity look like?

Comment: @UnSure  See my edit.

Comment: Alright thank you! Also your method does not work for other cases like SW since I think I need a decaying function rather than a doubling function any thoughts?

Comment: You should be able to get what you want by choosing the correct sign for $b$.

Comment: Your equations seem to be broken since I see them in the /frac version but I have been messing around with the values for a while now without much success.

Comment: If you [edit] the question to add just what you want for the SW quadrant (what values of the slope correspond to angles of 180, 225 and 270) I may be able to help. Tell me when you've done that.

Comment: Ok I edited my post with what I have now. So far I think I got two of them working.

Comment: I can't (won't) read your code. If you specify the desired angles that go with the slopes in each quadrant I may be able to find the formulas you want.

Comment: Ok I specified the angles I am looking for at the bottom of my post. I only have two out of 6 right now.

Comment: That is not a specification I can help you with. You need to describe exactly which slopes correspond to which angles at the start and middle and end for each separate case (as I asked in an earlier comment).

Comment: I provided all information and I even updated the image which depicts the slopes. I need an equation to find the angles from West to South West and by looking at the image you can see that the slope will go from 0 -> 1 when x is negative and z is positive. Then I need to do the same from South West to South when the slope goes from 1 -> to infinity. Then I need to do the same with the other 4 on the opposite side (South to SE, SE to East, East to NE, and NE to North. I provided all information I know and you can even see my attempts at creating an equation for each slope in my code above.